# Determining initial values for optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I am trying to solve an optimization problem with a quadratic objective function and non-linear constraints, using SQP (Sequential Quadratic Programming). I am attempting at doing the implementation in R. However, the R algorithm require initial values, that must satisfy the constraints.

I am not sure how can I easily determine an initial value for $y$ that satisfies both constraints. Here is the optimization problem:

[image]

Note that $b$ is a known vector, $c$ is a known constant, and $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of known matrix $A$.

Any help would be appreciated. If some sample/mock data is required, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have some conditions on $A, b$ and $c$ that guarantee feasibility? If not then I think this will be quite difficult, because finding a feasible point could be easily as difficult as solving the optimization problem. I would also suggest trying out solvers in MATLAB or trying to model this in AMPL/GAMS and running it on [NEOS](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/). Also have you looked into whether traditional SQP converges for non-convex QPs?

Comment: Is the $\sigma$ not positive semi-definite? Also I do not get how the logarithmic constraint works. Should we assume $b_i\sum \ln y_i \geq c_i$?

Comment: @AC_MOSEK Yes, $\Sigma$ is semi-positive definite and symmetric. The logarithmic constraint depends on an arbitrary constant $c$. Therefore, you can choose $c$ such that the constraint is satisfied.

Comment: @wonko Actually, there may or may not be a feasible solution to the problem. Also, this program is convex, since $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: I could provide the reference paper where such QP is implemented (application to finance), if that could be of help.

Comment: How is the log constraint convex? $\log y_j$ is convex so you have a sum of convex functions being $\geq$ a constant. This is not a convex constraint.

Comment: Never mind my bad.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to solve the QP $\text{max} \ b \sum \log y_j \quad \text{s.t.} \ {A^+}^T y \geq 0$. If the optimal value is at least as large as c, the optimal solution is a feasible point to your problem. I would honestly try for solvers that do not require an initial feasible point, or look for a specific algorithm for your problem as opposed to generic SQP.

Comment: @wonko I very much like your suggestion! Thanks, I will try it out!